# Template Mode in api.ai is not working with Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have on Dialogflow agent and I want to sync it with google assistant.
For user says section, I want to use Template mode. It works fine in api.ai, but when I click on option 'See how it works in Google Assistant', it throws error like '**Request contains an invalid argument.
Query pattern contains invalid characters in custom intent '999154f0-830a-480b-bdc9-2e9e89f45cdd': $SchemaOrg_Color:color $SchemaOrg_Text:query $quantifier:quantifier @sys.unit-currency:unit-currency $Filters:Filters**'
After checking each and every annotations, I came to know that @sys.unit-currency:unit-currency is creating issue. Its working with api.ai agent but not with google assistant.
I've attached screenshot of intent. What's need to be corrected? I went through many blogs, but not able to find any help regarding this.

[image]

Comment: are there more example phrases used?  some special chars have problems with Google Assistant

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue ?